# What is the method changing the size of wall in Famo.us platform?

Tags: famo.us

Does anyone know the method which changes the size of the wall in Famo.us platform?
I already found the property, distance, to locate the wall but having hard time to figure the size problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no size property of the wall object. From the documentation in the source. Wall describes an infinite 2D plane.

```
 *  A wall describes an infinite two-dimensional plane that physics bodies
 *    can collide with. To define a wall, you must give it a distance (from
 *    the center of the physics engine's origin, and a normal defining the plane
 *    of the wall.
 *
 *    (wall)
 *      |
 *      | (normal)     (origin)
 *      | --->            *
 *      |
 *      |    (distance)
 *      ...................
 *            (100px)
 *
 *      e.g., Wall({normal : [1,0,0], distance : 100})
 *      would be a wall 100 pixels to the left, whose normal points right
```

What you want is a rectangle collision, which is currently not supported. You will have to wait for a future release or write it yourself.